# Unable to open realm at path when device is locked

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

In my app I'm doing background sync of contacts, and when the device is locked the app crashes:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason:
>   '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FF77C6DA-970E-4FDD-AB69-C10C20607243/Documents/MyApp/default.realm.lock:
>   Unable to open a realm at path
>   '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FF77C6DA-970E-4FDD-AB69-C10C20607243/Documents/MyApp/default.realm.lock':
>   open() failed: Operation not permitted.'

I tried:

Creating a new folder:

```
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/MyApp"];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error]; //Create folder
```

and then create the .realm file in this folder, and set the file protection to None. along with NSFilePosixPermissions

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] setAttributes:@{NSFileProtectionKey: NSFileProtectionNone,
                                                    NSFilePosixPermissions : [NSNumber numberWithShort:0777]
                                                    }
                                     ofItemAtPath:[[[RLMRealm defaultRealm]configuration]fileURL].URLByDeletingLastPathComponent.path error:nil];
```

Still the app crashes when device is locked while syncing.

Any ideas on how to fix this ?

Comment: In the Xcode target entitlements, do you have data protection turned on? https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html

Comment: Yes, it is turned on!

Comment: After I turned it off, the crash didn't occur. Thanks for the info @BradBrighton

Comment: You're welcome. I'll post the comment in the answer so that the question can be closed. Glad it helped!

Comment: @Teja Nandamuri in your scenario can you explain how did you replicate the crash ? i am seeing crashes but i have no idea to replicate them please can you help.

Comment: I replicated it by having a timer to execute DB operations in background, and I lock the device to make the crash happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having data protection on intentionally interferes with access in certain conditions (like when the device is locked).

> The default level of protection is complete protection, in which files are encrypted and inaccessible when the device is locked. You can programmatically set the level of protection for files created by your app, as described in Protecting Data Using On-Disk Encryption in App Programming Guide for iOS. For files stored in shared containers (described in Configuring App Groups), set the level of protection programmatically.

(from https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html)

This link also shows where Data Protection is enabled in your Xcode project (specifically, the entitlements for a target), in the event that you're not sure if it's been enabled or not.

If your app needs the benefits of Data Protection but at a more granular level than all-or-nothing, you'll need to dig into the "Protecting Data Using On-Disk Encryption" section referenced in the copy from Apple's docs.

Comment: Does anyone know how to replicate this crash, if someone can explain their crash scenarios with examples will really help.